# How to integrate $\int \sin \sqrt{x}\, \mathrm dx$

Tags: integration

How do I integrate $\int \sin \sqrt{x} \, \mathrm  dx$ using a suitable substitution first?

Comment: A substitution will help, what substitution does it suggest?

Comment: Try $t=\sqrt{x}$, so $x=t^2$ and $dx=2tdt$.

Comment: That is what I am trying to get. It does not suggest one.

Comment: Obvious substitution: remove this problematic $\sqrt{x}$ by a friendly $u$.

Comment: And then, integration by parts

Answer (score 5):

With $x=u^2$, so $\mathrm{d}x=2u\mathrm{d}u$,

$$\int \sin\sqrt{x}\,\mathrm{d}x=2\int u\sin u \,\mathrm{d}u$$

Now you have an integral $P(u)\sin u$; where $P$ is a polynomial. The answer is thus of the form $Q\sin u+R\cos u$ (with polynomial $Q$ and $R$), whose derivative is

$$(Q'-R)\sin u+(Q+R')\cos u$$

Hence $Q+R'=0$ or $Q=-R'$, and $Q'-R=-R''-R=u$, so $R=-u$ and $Q=1$.

Hence

$$\int \sin\sqrt{x}\,\mathrm{d}x=2\int u\sin u \,\mathrm{d}u=2\sin u-2u\cos u+C=2\sin \sqrt{x}-2\sqrt{x}\cos \sqrt{x}+C$$

Comment: I think you mean "With $x=u^2$, so $\mathrm{d}x=2u\mathrm{d}u$", right?

Comment: @MPW Arf, yes of course :D Silly me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

$\bf{My\; Solution ::}$ Let $\displaystyle I = \int \sin \sqrt{x}dx\;,$ Now let $\displaystyle \sqrt{x}=t\;,$ Then $dx = 2\sqrt{x}dt = 2tdt$

So $\displaystyle I = 2\int t\cdot \sin t dt\;,$ Now Using Integration by Parts, We get

So $\displaystyle I = -2t\cdot \cos t+2\sin t+\mathcal{C}  = -2\sqrt{x}\cdot \cos \sqrt{x}+2\sin \sqrt{x}+\mathcal{C}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=t^2$ so we have $dx=2tdt$ and $\int2t\sin t dt=2(-t\cos t+\sin t)+ C=2\sin \sqrt{x}-2\sqrt{x}\cos \sqrt{x}+C$